# Best way to empty browser cache when developing/testing LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components, deployment, browser

I am developing a LWC, using Visual Studio, so I am frequently deploying JS, HTML and CSS file to the org. As a browser I use Chrome (latest version) under Windows 10.

What I am seeing: not updated or even previous versions of JS/HTML/CSS being active instead of the most recent sources. As a standard procedure I press Ctrl-F5 everytime the deploy is completed, but that is not always enough. Sometimes I have to restart the browser and even then it does not always work.

What is a sure-fire way of making the browser use the latest sources?

Answer (score 6):

You should [Disable Caching](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/debug_disable_caching.htm). This has obvious performance penalties, but should show the latest version of your code.

> 1. From Setup, enter Session in the Quick Find box, and then select Session Settings.
> 2. Deselect the checkbox for “Enable secure and persistent browser caching to improve performance”.
> 3. Click Save.

Comment: Hmm... in my version of Chrome (80.0.3987.132) searching for Session in the settings does not give any results. Search on cache/caching only enables manual deletion of the cache. Are you using Chrome under Windows or a different OS?

Comment: @SanderdeJong It's a Salesforce setting, not a browser setting. I apologize if that was unclear.

Comment: Ah... that explains it. Humans... so capable of creating misunderstandings. Thanks!

Comment: Another tip for development, Under Setup --> Develop --> Lightning Components --> Debug Mode, enable debug mode for your user to get un-minified versions of your JS code.

Comment: Sorry, I had to uncheck this as being an answer. I just noticed the same behaviour again. Caching in SF is off, I press Ctrl-F5 all the time in the browser and I just noticed a version of my JS code active that is at least a few hours old. And not the most recent version. Maybe it's a Chrome bug?