# Refresh lightning web component after making code changes without clearing browser cache

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am facing a peculiar issue while making changes to lightning web component.

Once the changes are done and deployed on to higher orgs, for some users the new javascript changes are not reflecting and the LWC is executing the older version of the javascript. Since Salesforce caches the definition of the LWC, it executes the outdated version of the javacript which is stored in the browser cache.  The issue is resolved only by clearing the browser cache for all the impacted users which is not a feasible solution for production.

Is there a way that the definition for LWC can be refreshed from the server so that the LWC always executes the latest code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best way to empty browser cache when developing/testing LWC?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/297325/best-way-to-empty-browser-cache-when-developing-testing-lwc)

Comment: Hi Sander, The link does not provide the answer. I should have stated earlier that the Enable secure and persistent browser caching to improve performance is enabled and it should not be disabled as recommended by Salesforce to get the performance benefits. So I am trying to find to refresh the LWC components , especially javacript whenever the user clicks on a button which opens the specific LWC.

Answer (score 0):

The 'secure and persistent browser caching' permission should be off in a development/testing environment, but should be on in your production org to avail performance benefits of caching.

The Caching on user's browsers will be cleared and loaded with the new LWC components over time (that's how cache's typically work). This obviously is a problem if your deployments are very frequent, since the cache will probably use the same LWC version until expiry.

There isn't a way other than disabling persistent caching to force the user's browser to load new versions of a component. You could temporarily disable it after a production release. This would force all browsers to reload their cache data. You can turn it back on again so that the performance benefits are passed to the users once they are done loading the new versions.

Comment: There are hundreds of users in production.So even if the persistent caching is disabled temporarily , there is no way to identify when all the users have used the tool so that the setting can be re-enabled.

Comment: you could coordinate that with their login history, or wait for a significant amount of time before enabling persistent caching. Over time, all the users browser caches will be cleared irrespective. This is just a way to make that process faster.