About LWC slow refresh
I have a problem with LWC development. After every change in the component, it doesn't matter if it is the JS file or HTML I need to logout from the Sandbox and login in order to see the changes. Is there any better solution?
Regards,
Ivo

Try enabling LWC debug, or turn off session caching.

Usually it's enough turning off session cache as Phil said. Setup > Session Settings > deselect "Enable secure and persistent browser caching to improve performance" > Save

Refer to this: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/373334/changes-are-not-visible-after-deployment-of-lwc  - https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54V00007T4GA2SAN

Thank you guys. It worked as a charm. Regards, Ivo

What works for me: switching languages.
